# API Call every time navigating to the Specific fragment - All lifecycle will be recall again

Tags: android, xml, navigation, components

In my app there is a screen called home screen, that call some api's when app open, but if user navigate through the home screen to the details screen and coming back from details screen to home screen it will called all api's again, There is any way to handle calling api again again everytime user navigate to the homescreen.

Comment: you have two ways, either just call the API once and then mark it to prevent further calls when a user comes back. or separate the lifecycle from the API call and just store the data. 
for calling it only once per run just store a boolean

Comment: lets keep it simple use flag when api call complete make its value true next time when came back to fragment check if value is true do not call the api  **Save flag value in shared preference or datastore**